# ./mage mage-setup

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I am very new to Magento and new to the upgrade. I have been trying to upgrade Magento 1.7.2 to 1.9.2 via SSH. I've created a localhost stage website before I go live but getting many errors. Starting with:

```
$ ./mage mage-setup
```

when I try `./mage sync` or any other function I get:

> Please initialize Magento Connect installer by running: ./mage
>   mage-setup

Please Help, Thank you in advance...

Comment: any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

On initial call, `./mage mage-setup` should result in output like

```
Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Successfully added: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```

An entry for the *community* channel should then be present in `./downloader/connect.cfg`. If given file remains unaltered, check if your SSH user has sufficient permissions.

Comment: Here is the only error I got from it:  [link] ./downloader/connect.cfg: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `}

Comment: Remove/backup the files `./downloader/connect.cfg` and `./downloader/cache.cfg` and try again.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it did not solve it. I guess I still have to figure out the permission in SSH